# How many blocks should I fall to take 9 hearts of fall damage together

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition, achievements

There is an, achievement of taking *nine hearts* damage at once. I have been trying to complete it for almost a month still every time I try the player dies or I take **8 1/2** hearts of damage. **How many blocks should I fall to take damage, or is there any other way to complete the achievement?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're misunderstanding the objective of the achievement. This is the achievement:

> **Overkill**: Deal nine hearts of damage in a single hit.

This means that in a single swipe of your sword, or a punch of your fist, you need to be able to deal nine hearts or more damage to an entity you're attacking. This is accomplished through enchantments and/or status effects.

You misunderstood the achievement as taking 9 hearts damage to yourself, when the achievement is for dealing 9 hearts damage to other mobs.